# Parse.com upload file max size

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I am trying to upload a 100MB video file to Parse, but I get an error code 129 : File size exceeds maximum allowed.

I have been trying to find the size contraints on the docs with no luck. Does any one know the actual file size limit?

I am using the REST API for the uploads.

Thanks

Comment: I would use a CDN for that.

Comment: My question is very specific about Parse, and it's file upload limitations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The size limit of a PFFile object is 10MB

> The PFFile
>
> PFFile lets you store application files in the cloud that would
>   otherwise be too large or cumbersome to fit into a regular PFObject.
>   The most common use case is storing images but you can also use it for
>   documents, videos, music, and any other binary data (up to 10
>   megabytes).

Taken from the iOS guide on PFFile, https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files/iOS