# App crashes when PFFile is too large

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

My app crashes when I try to upload a PFFile that is larger than 10mb. I thought that Parse would catch the error and I could display an alert view at this point, but instead the app just crashes.

My code below works fine for saving images, but like I said, it crashes if the file is too big.

I have tried to catch the error with if (error) statements, but no luck.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Football_Clubs"];

    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:objectId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
     {
         NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(badgeImage);
         PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.png" data:imageData];
         object[@"badge_image"] = imageFile;

         [imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
         {
             if (succeeded)
             {
                 [object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                     if (succeeded)
                     {
                         badgeImageView.image = nil;
                         [getSettingsQuery clearCachedResult];
                         [self loadSettings];
                         [progress setText:@"Saved"];
                     }
                 }];
             }
         } progressBlock:^(int percentDone)
         {
             [progress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Saving image - %d%@ complete", percentDone, @"%"]];
         }];
     }];
```

My console log is as follows:

2014-07-31 12:40:47.466 Sporter[21017:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'PFFile cannot be larger than 10485760 bytes'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18ae1ef50 0x1973281fc 0x18ae1ee90 0x10011d550 0x1000c6ae4 0x100141334 0x197900014 0x1978fffd4 0x1979031dc 0x18addec2c 0x18addcf6c 0x18ad1dc20 0x190a05c0c 0x18de4efdc 0x1000d5218 0x19791baa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: When you say the file is larger than 10mb? How do you know this? Also, are you sure it isn't just the app crashing due to memory pressure? What's the crash log? Note that an app crashing is not the same as an error.

Comment: @Fogmeister sorry - should have mentioned that. I mentions it in the console output when it crashes.

Comment: nick - that's an amazing, report, thanks for that.  I wonder if anyone else has seen this bug?  I posted it to the parse mailing list.  Can you edit in your crash log or the console log?

Comment: @JoeBlow sure - done.

Comment: Not at all. I know the max limit, and I dont wish to exceed it. I just want to handle the error rather than the app crash.

Comment: @nickjf89 the only thing I can think you might be able to do is to break down the NSData into chunks and store them in multiple PFFiles. Then concatenate them when they are downloaded back into NSData.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. I can upload files up to 10mb no problem. My issue is that when the file is more than 10mb, the app crashes, rather than giving me the option to catch this error and handle it. See in my code, the if (succeeded) - I should be able to catch the error here with if (error) but i isnt called, even though there is an error.

Comment: Well, just check the size of the NSData bytes surely? Before trying to put it into a `PFFile`.

Comment: ok, i guess thats an option. I'll try it.

Comment: Or wrap it in a `try catch` block.

Comment: That another option yes, i just assumed that like with other Parse.com methods, the error would catch itself using the block that I'm already using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The size limit of a PFFile object is 10MB

> The PFFile
>
> PFFile lets you store application files in the cloud that would
>   otherwise be too large or cumbersome to fit into a regular PFObject.
>   The most common use case is storing images but you can also use it for
>   documents, videos, music, and any other binary data (up to 10
>   megabytes).

Taken from the iOS guide on PFFile, https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files/iOS

> Reference answer from here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16729142/1603234

In your case, 10485760 bytes means 10.48576 megabytes. So that's maximum file size.

#### How to get a file size?

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:yourFilePath error:nil];
unsigned long long fileSize = [attributes fileSize]; // result would be in bytes

if(fileSize <= 10485760) {
    //you can continue for upload.
}else{
   //file size exceeding, can't upload.
}
```

However this is static, and not suggestible because if PARSE will change his mind and allowing double sized files to upload!

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers. If a question is a duplicate then vote to close it using the duplicate question.

Comment: @Fogmeister, Yes! I apologise for that. However I'm finding a solution for the question.

Comment: Yes, I know.
If you read the question, you'd see that I just wanted to be able to handle the error when a file that is more than 10mb is trying to be uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Example in **Swift**:

```
func imageFileSize() {
    let data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: myURL)!)!
    println("\(data.length) bytes")
    println("\( Double(data.length) * pow(Double(10.0), Double(-6.0)) ) MB") // MB: Megabytes
    println("\( Double(data.length) / pow(Double(2.0), Double(20.0)) ) MiB") // MiB: Mebibytes
    println("isFileSizeUpTo10Mebibytes(\(data.length)) returns: \(isFileSizeUpTo10Mebibytes(data.length))")
}

/* return true if fileSize <= 10485760 bytes
   else return false */
func isFileSizeUpTo10Mebibytes(fileSize: Int) -> Bool {
    return fileSize <= 10485760
}
```

Moreover there is an error in the iOS/OSX SDK documentation < Files part < The PFFile:

[image]

([Source of this information](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS))

It is 10 Mebibytes and not 10 Megabytes.